# How do I get changes to a unyt.unit_registry to change my calculations?

Tags: python

I'm using the unyt library and trying to make a custom unit_registry and/or update the default unit_registry.

I can successfully make a custom unyt_registry and add new units to it, but then I can't seem to access those as Unit objects. Even working in the default registry I can't modify custom units after I put them in. Here are some examples:

```
my_registry = unyt.UnitRegistry()
unyt.unit_object.define_unit('bushel', 0.5*unyt.kg, registry=my_registry)
print(my_registry['bushel'])
print(my_registry.bushel)
print(unyt.bushel)
```

The first print statement works and prints a dictionary entry for the values of the bushel unit as they were initialized, but both of the other print statements error.

```
import unyt
unyt.unit_object.define_unit('bushel', 0.5*unyt.kg)
print(unyt.bushel.base_value)
print(unyt.unit_registry.default_unit_registry['bushel'])
unyt.unit_registry.default_unit_registry.modify('bushel', 0.1*unyt.kg)
print(unyt.bushel.base_value)
print(unyt.unit_registry.default_unit_registry['bushel'])
```

Both of the `print(unyt.bushel.base_value)`s print 0.5, but the `print(unyt.unit_registry.default_unit_registry['bushel']` successfully updates and changes the base_value from 0.5 to 0.1.

What am I doing wrong? Intuitively I would expect there to be some method to update whatever calculation engine/registry in use but I can't find one. There's a way to set the default registry to something else but that didn't work either when I pointed it to a custom registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers: can't modify default registry (duh) and syntax for getting units from a custom registry is:

```
my_unit = unyt.Unit('bushel', registry = my_registry)
my_quantity = 2. * my_unit
```